# Deadlock on timer controlled db operation

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, timer

I have 3 identical programs (made using topshelf) that run as 3 separate services for 3 different departments. When they run, they keep accessing database using timers - mainly to keep sending Alive signal or to purge the old logs. Recently I've been asked to add additional timer only for one of the departments

```
 Random r = new Random();   //to avoid possible deadlock we save the timestamp on random time
        int hourly =  1000 * 60 * 60;     //this is an hour



       Timer TimerItem = new Timer(TimerCallBack, null, 0, r.Next(20000, 25000));  //alive timer
       Timer purgeLogs = new Timer(TimerPurgeLogs, null,0,hourly);    //purge logs timer
       if (selDep == "planners")
       {
           Timer UpdatePlannes = new Timer(TimerUpdatePlanners, null, 0, r.Next(50000,60000));    //planners update
       }



    private static void TimerUpdatePlanners (Object o)
    {
        string conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Sample.Properties.Settings.lynccallrosterConnectionString"].ToString();
        if (selDep == "planners") //Only for planners - auto turn the forwading on for everyone except the current person
        {
            string updateCommand = "update employees set on_call = 1 where Department ='Planners' and gkey <> (Select gkey from currently_on_call where Department ='Planners')";
            using (SqlConnection updatePlanners = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                SqlCommand executeUpdate = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, updatePlanners);
                try
                {
                    updatePlanners.Open();
                    executeUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    updatePlanners.Close();
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately after I've done this, it caused a hell of a problems with other program that is trying to read the same database, because it somehow deadlocked the database (SQL 2005).

I can't see the reason for deadlock here: timer is executed only every 50-60s and the command execution last few millisecond, yet it seems that the connection is kept open all the time - in the activity monitor I can see dozen or so Update commands that keep clogging the data traffic.

What is also interesting, this issue only happens when the program is run as a service  - topsehlf allows to run service as a console app and when its run in this mode, I can't see any deadlocks or unnecessary Update commands waiting in the queue.

What have I done wrong?

EDIT: I've tried as suggested to add `Dispose()` method in the try-catch

```
  try
                {
                    updatePlanners.Open();
                    executeUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    updatePlanners.Close();

                }
                catch { }
                finally
                {
                    executeUpdate.Dispose();
                    updatePlanners.Dispose();
                }
```

But that still doesn't solve the issue with deadlock.

EDIT2: I think I solved it using try-and-error method by adding the delay to the timer start:

```
Timer UpdatePlanners = new Timer(TimerUpdatePlanners, null, r.Next(10000, 20000), r.Next(10000, 20000));
```

It still bugs me why there are so many UPDATE spawning, but at least now they are not deadlocking each other, because each one spawns at different time from the service start/timer tick.

Comment: Have you tried disposing the SqlCommand's that are being created?

Comment: You mean manually kill them from the SQL Management studio Activity monitor? Well.. I did now, new one keep appearing as soon as I kill one

Comment: No, I mean actually calling .Dispose() on them. i.e. put them in a using() like your SqlConnection is.

Comment: I've tried now adding it just after updatePlanners.Close(); executeUpdate.Dispose(); - still the same. I've tried as well in the `finally` part of the `try-catch`